# how to neglect the media query style that overriding the desktop style in roadie gem?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, html-email

I am designing a mail template for my application using roadie gem. While sending a mail from my application i am getting that my desktop styles are overridden by media query style. For exact i want to display some content as a table view in desktop and normal paragraph view in handhold devises. In desktop it shows me as paragraph instead of table view. This is because roadie gem make all styles as inline and so my media query override the desktop style.Some one help me to solve this.

mailer.rb

```
class My_mailer < ActionMailer::Base
 layout 'email_design'
 include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

 def send_mail(user,product, count)
     @product = product
     @no.of.items = count
     mail(to: user.email, subject:'you are the new user')
 end
```

mobile.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
   .list{
    width: 100% ;
    border: none;
}
.list td{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: none;
}
.list th{
    display: none;
}
.hide-show{
    display: inline;
}
}
```

desktop.css

```
.list{
width: 90%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
.list td{
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
.list th {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}
 .hide-show{
display: none;
}
```

email_design.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/email_layout/desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/email_layout/mobile.css" data-immutable />
 </head>
```

send_mail.html.erb

```
<table class="list">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>no.of.item</th>
  </tr>
  <% .each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td class="m-bold" style="padding: 10px"><%= product.full_name %></td>
        <td style="padding: 10px"><span class="hide-show">No.of.items:</span><%=@no.of.items %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this? @Sami

Answer (score 1):

You should know two things when figuring out this issue:

- roadie will delete your head styles and put them inline
- media queries are ignored by most clients([they work mostly on mobile mail apps](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/)). Gmail in the browser will not scale your email no matter how big the screen is.

To have the desired behavior, you should put the `data-roadie-ignore` in the style tag of your mobile styles like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mobile.css" data-roadie-ignore />
```

doing this, roadie will ignore the mobile styles, it will not delete them, nor inline them. It will inline just the desktop styles which will apply on most clients. Whenever the email is opened in a client that is interested in the media queries, the mobile styles will be there and will take effect.

Comment: I was bothered by this problem for a while. This answer definitely solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the media query styles a bit differently so that they are not picked up by desktop.

Instead of writing: `.myclass`, you would have to write:

```
*[class*="myclass"] { /*rules go here*/ }
```

and `#myID` would become:

```
*[id*="myID"] { /*rules go here*/ }
```

The first `*` makes sure you are selecting any element with that class name.

The second `*` insures that you able to apply more than 1 class to an element and it will still get picked up. `*=` means `containing`. Without the `*` it just means `equal to`.